# Installed and uninstalled LearnPress plugin, but it still redirects me from example.com/courses to example.com/lp-courses

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

So I was implementing an LMS to my website and figured why not try learnpress, but it wasn't compatible with my site so I had to remove it. I am now making my own page at example.com/courses but it keeps getting redirected to example.com/lp-courses and that leads to 404 error. Please help.

Comment: Install a plugin that adds a cpt, go to permalinks and save. Uninstall it, go back to permalinks and save.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you preview the page you created from the "Add New Page" and lookup the permalink structure. If the preview url is what you want then everything is all right else you need to change the permalink structure under settings options.

Here is guide on changing the permalink structure:: 
[Codex: Using Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: When I preview the page I am shown a preview of what I want, ie, example.com/courses?=preview
But when I am actually going to example.com/courses, it gets redirected to example.com/lp-courses

Comment: this means your wordpress is being routed. Some settings of the previous plugin may still be in effect. Lookup for your .htaccess file and try to create a new one by changing the permalink structure more than once in the settings page from the above link.